# How to back to dashboard after Drawer is clicked in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I Have problem in my navigation drawer, so after my drawer menu is clicked, its go to another page but when im press back button then its make my application closed, what i want here is when im press the back button its go back to dashboard instead of close the application here is my code in navigation drawer

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using KGVC.Views.UsersInfo;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using KGVC.Models;
using KGVC.Views.RssFeed;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace KGVC.Views.MainPages
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
    {
        public List<MasterPageItem> menuList { get; set; }

        public MainPage()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            menuList = new List<MasterPageItem>();

            // Creating our pages for menu navigation
            // Here you can define title for item, 
            // icon on the left side, and page that you want to open after selection
            var page0 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Dashboard", Icon = "icon_home.png", TargetType = typeof(MainPage) };
            var page1 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Users Profile", Icon = "icon_home.png", TargetType = typeof(BioUsers) };
            var page2 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Points", Icon = "icon_point.png", TargetType = typeof(RssFeedView) };
            var page3 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Inbox", Icon = "icon_inbox.png", TargetType = typeof(TestPage1) };
            var page4 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Card Community", Icon = "icon_community.png", TargetType = typeof(TestPage1) };
            var page5 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Offers & Promotion", Icon = "icon_point.png", TargetType = typeof(Logout) };
            var page6 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Info & Service", Icon = "icon_info", TargetType = typeof(Logout) };


            // Adding menu items to menuList
            menuList.Add(page0);
            menuList.Add(page1);
            menuList.Add(page2);
            menuList.Add(page3);
            menuList.Add(page4);
            menuList.Add(page5);
            menuList.Add(page6);


            // Setting our list to be ItemSource for ListView in MainPage.xaml
            navigationDrawerList.ItemsSource = menuList;

            // Initial navigation, this can be used for our home page
            Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(GridMenu)));
        }

        private void OnMenuItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            var item = (MasterPageItem)e.SelectedItem;
            Type page = item.TargetType;

            Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(page));
            IsPresented = false;
        }


    }
}
```

and here is my MasterPageItem class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace KGVC.Views.MainPages
{
    public class MasterPageItem
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Icon { get; set; }
        public Type TargetType { get; set; }
        public ICommand Command { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ho to make that happen, should i change anyting or is this possible to do that ?

Comment: Are you press hardware back button or application back button?

Comment: i press the hardware back button

Comment: look at my answer Hope its help!!

Comment: I didnt know about the activator class...that takes care of one big switch statement in my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the OnBackPressed in MainActivity(Android)

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
{
    if(App.Instance.DoBack)
    {
        base.OnBackPressed();
    }
}
```

In my xamarin forms app (App.Instance (it is a singleton))

```
public bool DoBack
{
    get
    {
        MasterDetailPage mainPage = App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage;

        if (mainPage != null)
        {    
            bool canDoBack = mainPage.Detail.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count > 1 || mainPage.IsPresented;

            // we are on a top level page and the Master menu is NOT showing
            if (!canDoBack)
            {
                // don't exit the app just show Dashboard
                //mainPage.IsPresented = true;

                Type page = typeof(MainPage);

                mainPage.Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(page));
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }                    
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**--- Edited ---**

```
static App _instance;
public static App Instance { get { return _instance; } }
```

Set _instance=this; in App()

Comment: i have question bro in main activty when i write  App.Instance.DoBack its said App Doesnt contain Instance , so what code should i write here ? how i define instance in here as field or something else ?

Comment: Instance is static variable is return instance of the App

Comment: sorry i just reply you but thanks for you answer its work , maybe need litle bit customation but thanks

Comment: well but now the problem is the application is cannot exit ahahahah,  because when i pressed the back button in the dashboard its go to dashboard again instead closing the application but thanks bro for your answer